# Expand all at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have an Expand All button on my website. I have two levels of expanding and collapsing links and would like to have an option to Expand All when someone wants to see everything without clicking. I think I know what I need to do - loop through all accordions and set them to display. Could you give me some tips.

This is the code. Please  help.

```js
function ExpandAll() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionMain");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    var panel = this.Children
    panel.style.display = "block";

  }

}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Accordion</h2>
  <button onclick="ExpandAll();">Expand All</button>
  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: you forgot to tell us what problem you're having. We can't fix an unknown issue.

Comment: First of all, you don't have an element with class `accordionMain` that you're trying to access in your `ExpandAll` function.

Comment: and even if you had elements with class `accordionMain` you don't use the `acc` variable at all in your loop in `ExpandAll()`

Comment: also in the same loop- `var panel = this.Children` doesn't make much sense as `this` would refer to the window obj. You probably would want `var panel = acc[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpandAll()` should be `expandAll()` (May not matter but it bothered me) 
Make sure to change it for the `onclick` for your button as well.

```
<button onclick="expandAll();">Expand All</button>
```

---

Then change your code to not look for `acordionMain` but for the `panel`. The `getElementsByClassName(X)` returns and array. So you can just iterate through that array and set the style to `display: "block"` via JS. The code is below.

```
<script>
        function expandAll ()
        {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var panel = elements[i];
                panel.style["display"] = "block";

                }

        }
    </script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

*Here is a Fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/CraftingGamerTom/f6y96c2e/

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing wrong. I was looking for accordions and not for panels. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help Irma. To benefit the community, please mark this post as the solution to your problem so it can easily be found.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask document to give you all `.panel` elements to show as below

```js
function ExpandAll() {
  var pannels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
 
  for (panel of pannels)
    panel.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button onclick="ExpandAll();">Expand All</button>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```